# If you deposit the amount you need to achieve your goal in $20$ years, how much will your savings be worth after 10 years?

Tags: statistics

How much should you invest each month in order to have $\$800,000$ if your rate of return is $5.3\%$ compounded monthly and you want to achieve your goal in $40$ years $\$484.5267545$

How much interest will you earn? $\$567,427.1578 $

How much should you invest each month in order to have $\$800,000$ if you want to achieve your goal in $20$ years? $1879.790424$

If you deposit the amount you need to achieve your goal in 20 years, how much will your savings be worth after $10$ years?

Having some trouble with this last problem asking for assistance. Other problems has been done. Thanks!

Comment: It is asking how much interest you would make in 10 years if you invested \$484.5267545 per month.

Comment: This seems to be a compound interest question from business math. I do not see the connection to statistics.